# Testing try-catch blocks in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, exception

Is there any viable way to **test** which `Exception` was caught by the catch blocks in the below Java method found below, without changing its current implementation.

```
public String methodToTest(String text) {
    try
    {
        if (text.contains("something")) {
            throw new CustomException();
        }

        final MyObj myObj = new MyObj(text); //this can throw a MyObjException

        return text;

    } catch (CustomException e) {
        return "An exception has been thrown";
    } catch (MyObjException e) {
        return "An exception has been thrown";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "An exception has been thrown";
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann if a certain exception was raised

Comment: Your method does not raise those exceptions since it catches them. You could test whether `new MyObj(text)` throws instead.

Comment: but I am interested in which error was actually caught by the catch block found in its body

Comment: why are you interested in the internals? it is enough to test the contract, requirements

Comment: I agree with both of you guys, but I just want to see if there is any way to achieve this.

Comment: I am afraid there is no way then. (Of course there always is a way it depends on how desperate you are and how deep you want to go. For example you could write your own JVM, etc.)

Comment: Why catch specific exceptions and apply the same logic? You are trying to test bad implementation in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not test the implementation of the method, you should test what you expected from the method. Here are some examples for the method that you provide:

- You expect the `text` that contains `"something"` to receive `"An exception has been thrown"`:

Test:

```
String result = obj.methodToTest("my_something_string");
assertEquals("An exception has been thrown", result);
```

- You expect for `text` that is `null` to receive `"An exception has been thrown"`:

Test:

```
String result = obj.methodToTest(null);
assertEquals("An exception has been thrown", result);
```

- You expect for the `text` that is not valid for `MyObj` to receive `"An exception has been thrown"`

Test:

```
String result = obj.methodToTest("string_not_valid_for_my_obj");
assertEquals("An exception has been thrown", result);
```

The same way test the other expected scenarios. Do not test the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If your mission is to treat the function as a "black box" for testing purposes, your only option is to rely on its return-value since *it* catches the exceptions.

If the return-value is identical in each case, as here, you simply cannot distinguish between them.

Your attempts at testing the function should not rely on knowledge of its implementation, nor should it materially alter how the function runs.  Therefore, in my opinion, this is the unfortunate answer.